# What is the "best" good kernel?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

A family of functions $k_n(x):[-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb R$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ is said to be a good kernel if all the following are satisfied:

1. $\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi}^\pi k_n(x) \, \mathrm d x=1$,
2. $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi |k_n(x)| \, \mathrm d x=O(1)$ where the implied constant is independent of $n$,
3. for each $\varepsilon>0$ we have  $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\varepsilon<|x|\leq \pi} |k_n(x)| \, \mathrm d x=0$.

This is a standard definition in Fourier analysis, see, for example, the book of Stein--Shakarchi "Fourier analysis" page 48.

For example, if $$ k_n(x) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z \\ |k| \leq n} \exp(-\pi k^2/n^2) \mathrm e^{2\pi i k x}$$
then the integral in the third property has size roughly $\exp\left(-\pi \epsilon^2 n^2\right).$

QUESTION: is there a good choice for $k_n$ that makes the limit in $(3)$ be  $$ o_{n\to +\infty }\left( \exp\left(-\pi \epsilon^2 n^2\right)\right)?$$

More importantly, is there any literature on this type of question?

Comment: What do you mean by "super fast"?

Comment: As a function of $n$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: What do you mean here? Would every function whatsoever of $n$ and $\epsilon$ be considered super fast by you?

Comment: The problem is, if you take a subsequence $k_{n_i}$ then it will also be a good kernel, and this way you can accelerate the convergence however you want by a diagonal process. So it is not clear what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Thank you Iosif Pinelis and Aleksei Kulikov for the questions! I added some detail and an example to explain a little bit better what I meant.

Comment: Your post is clearer now. Yet, as Alexei said, you can just take any subsequence $(k_{n_j})$ of $(k_n)$ and thus make the convergence however fast.